# Cassandra table structure suggestion and way of query

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I am trying to create a following hierarchy:
**UserId** as rowKey, **Hourly time series** as columns and inside each hourly column I want to have a **user specific information** such as hourly activity.

```
{
   UserId:long
   {
      Timestamp:datetime{
         pageview: integer,
         clicks:integer
      }
   }
```

I've read that it is possible to achieve it using `supercolumns` but at the same time it was mentioned that `supercolumns` are outdated right now. If it is true, any alternatives I can use?

Could you please provide me CQL / Java thrift example how should I create and insert such type of structure in Cassandra?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user composite primary key for this, I add a table creation CQL query for the table. And you can use counter column for clicks.

```
CREATE TABLE user_click_by_hour(
userid long,
time_stamp timestamp,
clicks int,
pageview int,
PRIMARY KEY(userid,time_stamp)
```

)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Another quick question! do you know how I can make my time_stamp round data to hours of day and do not include minutes?

Comment: I think you can do it in programming level. Eg: java or python

Answer (score 0):

If your information is subjected to a particular used and accessed together . For example,if you are at anytime , require both clicks and pageview, i would suggest you to use it as a json store

```
CREATE TABLE user_click_by_hour(
userid long,
time_stamp timestamp,
val text,
PRIMARY KEY(userid,time_stamp)
)
```

val is a json object containing clicks, pageview and etc.

**Advantage**

1.You need not worry about altering the table for adding extra column, which add a null value for each and every previous entry

1. If this data is designated to grow, you are bound to save a lot of space as there is one less column metadata in each node